# MX Notify Control doesn't work on statuses that contain spaces

Tags: mx-notify

I've just learned that MX Notify Control apparently sends a "Disallowed Key Characters" error when trying to set up a new rule for a status that contains spaces, like "Awaiting Approval." If I name that status "Awaiting-Approval", the notification does go through.

Any fix for this?

EE 2.9.2
Mx Notify 2.4.6

Comment: Hi Mike, did you find a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find a fix: https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-notify-control/pull/4 (I haven't tried if this works)